# Large Number Modulo Computation

Tags: totient-function

**Compute the following**:

a) $2^{208} \pmod{53}$

b) $2^{288} \pmod{73}$

c) $7^{19} \pmod{28}$

**Here is what I did so far:**

a) `∅ (53) = 52`

$(2^{52})^4 => (1)^4 => 1$

b) `∅ (73) = 72`

$(2^{72})^4 => (1)^4 => 1$

c) `∅ (28) = 12`

$7^{12} * 7^7 \pmod{28}$

$1 * 7^7 \pmod{28} => 7$

Just wondering if what I've worked out is correct?

Comment: The caret doesn't seem to work.

Comment: yes its not working for some reason, maybe i missed the formatting?

Comment: You need to put \$ around formulae: \$7^7\$ produces $7^7$.  Also use \mod{28} not mod 28.

Comment: For the last, we have $7^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $7^6\equiv 0\pmod{7}$ so $7^6\equiv 1\pmod{38}$  without computation (to be unnecessarily fancy here, we are using the Carmichael $\lambda$-function). So $7^{19}\equiv 7^1\pmod{28}$.